# How can I get a random (/dev/random) number between 0 and 999999999 in bash?

Tags: bash, random

For example,

```
echo "$(( ($(od -An -N2 -i /dev/random) )%(1000-0+1) ))"
```

can be used. But it doesn't scale for bigger numbers.

How can I get a random (/dev/random) number between 0 and 999999999 in bash?

Comment: Can you just put 3 of those in a row?

Comment: Generate 9 1 digit ones and append them with powers of 10, the law of large numbers says it's the same random distribution although since `/dev/random` isn't that random it'll break but it's broken anyway so... :D

Comment: `Can you just put 3 of those in a row?` - That would be a different random number than doing it in one go?

Answer (score 7):

I'd use:

```
shuf -i0-999999999 -n1
```

although there is no guarantee that `shuf` uses `/dev/random`. With GNU `shuf` you can specify `--random-source=/dev/random` if you really want to.

IIRC, FreeBSD (and probably Mac OS X) call this utility `shuffle`, and it takes slightly different arguments (`shuffle -n1000000000 -p1`).

If you really want to use `/dev/random` directly, you can generate a four-byte number by using `od -An -N4 -tu4` but remember that there is a bias generated by using `%1000000000`, since 2<sup>32</sup> is not divisible by `1000000000`. To correct for that, in the particular case of generating random numbers in the range `0-999999999`, you need to reject the four-byte random number if it is greater than or equal to `4000000000`.

Comment: Not really between 0 and 999999999? I've run this like 100 times and always got results with 8 or 9 digits. Never smaller numbers such as 443242.

Comment: @adrenalos: the odds of getting a seven-digit number is 1 in 100. So 100 repetitions is not a very good test.

Comment: smallest numbers are much less probable. 100 times clearly not enough to get them.

Comment: +1 This should be accepted as the answer. Missed your explanation when posting mine which essentially does the same thing (though this one is probably slightly faster).

Answer (score 1):

**Explenation**

The key to doing this using `/dev/random` is thinking about what produces a uniform distribution. `/dev/random` does, but doing

```
 od -An -N2 -i /dev/random
```

Provides a 2-byte output, which is uniform over 0...2<sup>16</sup>-1 or 0...65535. But obviously not uniform over 0...99999.

Taking it mod 1000, will change the output to 0...999, but the distribution still won't be uniform over it.

**Solution**

Let's say we have a pseudo-random generator that produces 0,1,2,3,4, but we want one that produces 0,1. We just ignore any output 2,3,4 and keep outputs 0,1 which by definition must still be pseudo-random.

So, you can do something like this.

To get a single digit you can do something like this

```
while :; do ran=$(echo $(od -An -N1 -i /dev/random)) && [[ $ran -lt 250 ]] && \
echo ${ran: -1} && break; done
```

since the distribution of the least significant digit between 0...249 is uniform.

Then to build a 9 digit random number, just do something like

```
#!/bin/bash

digit() {
  while :; do ran=$(echo $(od -An -N1 -i /dev/random)) && [[ $ran -lt 250 ]] && \
  echo ${ran: -1} && break; done
}

for ((i=0; i<9; i++)) {
  num+=$(digit)
}

echo $num
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 cat /dev/random | tr -cd 0-9 | dd bs=1 count=9
```

Cat random data from `/dev/random`, delete all except `0`, `1`, ... `9`; then wait only for 9 digits with dd.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `awk`, which should be available on pretty much any UNIX-like box:

```
awk 'BEGIN{print int(rand()*999999999)}'
```

Comment: Does this use `/dev/random`?

Comment: It does not, since there's a method `srand()` for seeding the generator, which implies a pseudo-random generator. `strace -eopen awk 'BEGIN{print int(rand()*999999999)}'` doesn't show opening `/dev/random`, either. But, you could read some data from `/dev/random/` to seed the pseudo-random number generator using `srand()`. It's not as good as using `/dev/random` directly, though.